# PHP / DOM - get html tags in addition to content

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I am trying to retrieve everything from within html element but it only returns the content of the element.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('/html/body/main/div/section/article');

if ($elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {    
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The **article** element holds many things beside the textual content.
How to retrieve it? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you get with : `foreach ($elements as $element)` **{echo "<br/>". $element->nodeName. ": ";** `$nodes = $element->childNodes; .....`

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a node as the argument to `DOMDocument::saveHtml()`:

```
echo $dom->saveHtml($node);
```